# Div next to div, 50%-50% and after a minimum width, linebreak and 100%

Tags: css, html

This is what I want to achieve:

```
DIV1 50%          |          50% DIV2 |
DIV1 50%      |      50% DIV2 |
```

and after a width (the user shrinks the window, lets say below 300px)

```
DIV1 100%       |
DIV2 100%       |
```

so I want a linebreak and be them 100%.

This is I got so far:

```
<div>50%</div>
<div>50%</div>

div
{
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MYs96/

but thats no good, they cant be 100%. I heard about mediaquery (Im new to it), does it might solve this problem? And if I dont want to use mediaquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this

```
div {width:50%; float:left;}

@media all and (max-width: 300px)  {
  div { width:100%; float:none;}
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/HDdv9/4/)

[More information about media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
div
{
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 300px;
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
          width: 100%;
         } 
}
```

Comment: is it valid to embed @media into this? Ive never seen it before

Comment: oops yes, I meant embed into DIV declaration? It doesnt seem to work